# ADODB recordset column headers

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb

I'm copying `ADODB.Recordset` data to excel file, but it copies the recordset data to excel without column headers.I'm using MS Access 2013, `CompyFromRecordset` command.

my question is, is there any way to copy the data headers of RecordSet?

```
For i = 0 To iFieldCount - 1
    objSheet.Range("A" & i + 1).CopyFromRecordset rst
    objBook.Save
Next i
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "header" is not a record and the `CopyFromRecordset` command does not include the headers.

You must put the header in your sheet yourself by iterating over the fieldnames of the returned recordset, something like:

```
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next
Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```