# Run-time error while fetching data from SQL Server through Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to fetch some data from a SQL server to excel using VBA. After researching on web, I have cobbled up a code and when I execute it, it throws a

> Run-time error -'2147217900 (80040e14)':
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

From the error it seems that the error is detected due to some abnormality in the query. The query was provided by the DBA team and incorporates data from 2 different tables. I used the same query to manually export data from the database to excel and it works. I don't know why vba is throwing error. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub sync_data_vba_sqlserver()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlQry As String, strCon As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents

sqlQry = "SELECT A.PUMA_TSD_PollID AS ID, PUMA_TSD_FieldName AS Field_Name,PUMA_TSD_FieldValue AS Field_Value,PUMA_TSD_IPAddress AS IP_Address,PUMA_TSD_PollDate AS Poll_Date,PUMA_TSD_Channel AS Channel,PUMA_TSD_MachineName AS Machine_Name,PUMA_TSD_TestBedType AS TestBedType FROM [WWW_AUXMOD].[dbo].[tblPUMA_TSD_AVLLynx] A INNER JOIN [WWW_AUXMOD].[dbo].tblPUMA_TSD_AVLLynxData L ON A.PUMA_TSD_PollID = L.PUMA_CH_TSD_PollID ON A.PUMA_TSD_PollID = L.PUMA_CH_TSD_PollID WHERE PUMA_TSD_MachineName != 'ELMS_SYSTEM' AND PUMA_TSD_PollDate >= '6/2/19';"


'---- Replace below highlighted names with the corresponding values

strCon = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=ECCDB1503.MD3Q.FORD.COM;Initial Catalog=WWW_AUXMOD;Integrated Security=SSPI"

'---  Open   the above connection string.

con.Open (strCon)

    rs.Open sqlQry, con
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close

con.Close
Set rs = Nothing


End Sub
```

Expecting the data to be exported to Excel from SQL Server.

Comment: ta L ON A.PUMA_TSD_PollID = L.PUMA_CH_TSD_PollID ON A.PUMA_TSD_Po  this part, you have 2 ON statements in a row  probably needs to be AND

Comment: Some basic formatting would reveal these types of issues quickly. Or even better, move this query to a stored procedure. Either way I voted to close this as it is just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulled your query out and pasted here.  Comment below, but removed ON and changed to AND.  You had 2 ON's in a row.

```
SELECT A.PUMA_TSD_PollID AS ID, PUMA_TSD_FieldName AS Field_Name,PUMA_TSD_FieldValue AS Field_Value,PUMA_TSD_IPAddress AS IP_Address,PUMA_TSD_PollDate AS Poll_Date,PUMA_TSD_Channel AS Channel,
PUMA_TSD_MachineName AS Machine_Name,PUMA_TSD_TestBedType AS TestBedType 
FROM [WWW_AUXMOD].[dbo].[tblPUMA_TSD_AVLLynx] A 
INNER JOIN [WWW_AUXMOD].[dbo].tblPUMA_TSD_AVLLynxData L ON A.PUMA_TSD_PollID = L.PUMA_CH_TSD_PollID 
    -- change ON to AND HERE  (ON IS REMOVED)
    --AND A.PUMA_TSD_PollID = L.PUMA_CH_TSD_PollID (Redundant statement) 
WHERE PUMA_TSD_MachineName != 'ELMS_SYSTEM' 
AND PUMA_TSD_PollDate >= '6/2/19'
```

Comment: How do I store the query inside my 'sqlQry' variable in multilines instead of the whole query in a single line?

Comment: And now it's throwing me Compile error: User-defined type not defined!!!

Comment: No need to change it to an AND, just remove the second one as they are identical. :)

Comment: Good catch Sean Lange, You can keep it single line, instead of changing to AND, just remove that section of code from your single line, so remove this:  ON A.PUMA_TSD_PollID = L.PUMA_CH_TSD_PollID

Comment: That worked. The only issue I see now is no header or column labels being fetched..how do I fetch the records along with the column headers?

Comment: Your column headers come with the data, but you need to do something extra to get them.  I am not familiar with VBA but they are not part of the data, there should be a call or something to get them.

Comment: CopyFromRecordset only copies the data, not the headers: you will need to loop over the recordset's `Fields` collection and get the `Name` of each field  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568793/adodb-recordset-column-headers

Comment: Thanks..I incorporated the loop and it's working as expected.